# BinaryReader (c#) в delphi 7

Tags: c#, delphi, binary

В `c#` был удобный компонент `BinaryReader`, с ним можно было удобно записывать строки и числа (`.Write`), а так же легко было считать (`.ReadInt32(), Read`). Не подскажите, есть ли что то подобное для `delphi 7` ? с `delphi` давно не работал и уже все забыл.

В частности нужно :

1. Записывать и считывать строки
2. Записывать и считывать числа

В c# для того, что бы записывать и считать число я мог сделать так :

```
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
writer.Write( aa.Length);

.....

var len = fss.ReadInt32()+5
```

Как такое же проделать в delphi 7 ?

Comment: `TStream.Write`/`TStream.Read`

Comment: `TBinaryReader`  `TBinaryWriter`  - не прям копия как в C#, но вроде то что вам нужно. Free не забудьте вызвать в finally)

Comment: да, спасибо, не думал, что все так просто тут :)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan не подскажите, я через `Filestream ` записываю
`S.Seek(S.Size, soFromBeginning); S.WriteBuffer( i, SizeOf(i));` , а потом читаю   `Stream.Seek(Stream.Size-4, soFromBeginning);
  Stream.ReadBuffer(Size,SizeOf(Integer)); `, всегда значение будет равно 4 байтам ? именно размер файла, ибо в c# всегда 4 байта занимало и я статически переходил на -4 с конца

Comment: Лучше используйте `Stream.Seek(-SizeOf(integer), soEnd); Stream.ReadBuffer(mySize, SizeOf(integer));` Только не надо забывать, что Seek - это функция. И если по каким-либо причинам указатель в файле не удалось передвинуть (например - размер файла 3, 2, 1 или 0 байт) - это покажет именно она.

Comment: @kami да, спасибо, наверное, так будет удобнее